# Passing a variable into an initialization of an array as a reference in a function parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, function, variables, parameters

I've been trying to learn C++ recently, and doing some hacker rank introductory tasks. I am attempting to do the https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/deque-stl challenge, but I am very unfamiliar with c++ syntax and uses of their base "array". If I would prefer, I would at the very least use std::array (although I understand that is nothing but a zero overhead wrapper of the default C array).

My problem is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque> 
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;
void printKMax(int (&arr)[n], int n, int k){
   //Write your code here.
    deque<int> d(arr);
    cout << arr[3];
    for(int i:d) {cout <<i;}

}
int main(){

   int t;
   cin >> t;
   while(t>0) {
      int n,k;
       cin >> n >> k;
       int i;
       int arr[n];
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin >> arr[i];
       printKMax(arr,n, k);
       t--;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

I am trying to pass the arr into printKMax, and receive it as a reference.
The error I am receiving is:

```
!‘arr’ was not declared in this scope
!‘n’ was not declared in this scope
!variable or field ‘printKMax’ declared void
!expected primary-expression before ‘int’
!expected primary-expression before ‘int’
```

of which if I use a constant int, eg "5", arr[5], it passes through.(passing arr[5] in the function call too). But if I replace with n, it doesn't work.

That is, at the moment, it is printKMax(arr,n,k) at the function call [not the definition], and I see no reason to add the arr[n] here (as it is already implicit in the array it is declared as: int arr[n]). I am trying to pass it as a reference, without it decaying into a pointer. I have messed around with passing it as *arr too, but with no success.

I read online its important to keep it as (&arr)[100] or something along those lines, but here I have (&arr)[n], and it is out of scope. I would love to just write (&arr)[], but alas I get this error instead:

```
parameter ‘arr’ includes reference to array of unknown bound ‘int []’
```

Thanks in advance! Also, is this only a problem with arrays? If I start using  and  and such data structures from eg the boost library, will I encounter similar problems?

PS: ignore the deque code, I was just playing around, trying to initialise it with the same elements as the array I am passing. It is probably incompatible since one is std:: and the other is default array unfortunately...?